# Lightning tab label showing "Loading..." in Service Console (bug)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, service-cloud-console, tab, label, service-console

I have a blank Lightning component which I am using as a custom tab in Service Console. While the content loads fine the tab label stays on "Loading..." forever.

**Component**
[image]

**Tab**
[image]

**Screen**
[image]

There are no errors in the Chrome console. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
The label displays fine if I add the same tab to my custom app.

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @KeithC no errors.

Comment: Maybe this is not problem this component but one of AccountSearch or AccountSearchList. Can you add code of them and picture with your custom tab settings?

Comment: @JJanek I have tried removing the body and still seeing the same behaviour. So the issue doesn't seem to be related to other components.

Comment: @KeithC here's an update: this seems to be only happening with Lightning tabs in Service Console. If I add the tab to my own custom app the label shows fine.

Comment: Salesforce is [aware of the issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001D3FQAU&title=lightning-component-tab-labels-display-as-loading-in-lightning-console-apps), not fixed yet as of Summer '18

Answer (score 5):

Put this line in Component.

```
//in markup
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
```

In Component init:

```
    //Js Controller
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            label: "Edit Contact" //set label you want to set
        });
        workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            icon: "utility:add_contact", //set icon you want to set
            iconAlt: "Edit Contact" //set label tooltip you want to set
        });
    })
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is now possible to set the Tab Label using the **Lightning Console JavaScript API** (GA as of Winter 18).

**[setTabLabel() for Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_setTabLabel.htm)**

The example in the documentation uses a button to update the tab label, but you could just as easily set it on init of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line in component :

`<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>`

Add the following code to the js controller of the component:

`doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.openTab({
            url : '/lightning/n/yourcomponentnamefromurl',
            focus: true
        }).then(function(response){
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: response ,
                label: "Label for tab" 
            })
        });`

This would avoid the condition of tab label changed to some other custom tab label when a second tab is opened.

Comment: Please avoid asking for upvotes in your posts, it is not relevant to the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite stuck too. Here's my code:

```
viewAllData: function(component, event, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(enclosingTabId){
        workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
        parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
        pageReference: {
            "type": "standard__component",
            "attributes": {"componentName": "c__BrandProfile360Cmp"},
            "state": {"uid": "1", "c__inputBPId": component.get("v.recordId")}
            }
        });
        workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
            tabId: enclosingTabId,
            label: "My Custom Label!" //set label you want to set
        });
    });
}
```